# Multiple Include/ThenInclude causing duplicates in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Ok, so I have a table Building which includes all Persons in that building.  However each Person has a profession which is a entity in itself that is added to the Person entity depending what is available.

```
var data = _dbcontext.Building
        .Where(m => m.BuildingId == buildingId)
        .Include(x => x.Person).ThenInclude(x => x.Doctor)
        .Include(x => x.Person).ThenInclude(x => x.Teacher)
        .Include(x => x.Person).ThenInclude(x => x.Farmer)
        .Include(x => x.Person).ThenInclude(x => x.Prostitute);
```

This is how I found to do it online, but it seems to literally be including the Person entity 4 times, so I have tons of duplicates.  I really only want it once, but I want to left join the profession entities as available.

The Foreign keys are all setup properly and I used EF to create my models. Here is what the Person entity looks like:

```
public partial class Person {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int? DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int? TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int? FarmerId { get; set; }
    public int? ProstituteId { get; set; }
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }

    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public Farmer Farmer { get; set; }
    public Prostitute Prostitute { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a 4 joins in sql-query or what?

Comment: What do you mean? The code I am using is above, just a Where/Include/ThenInclude

Comment: And what problem? Writing `Include(x => x.Person)` 4 times? It's by design, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to load the persons one time and join tables that match, from my research, this is the way to do that, but instead of loading it once, it loads it each time.  If this is not the way, then what is?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was not loading multiple times because of the Includes, but one of my classes had a collection of persons of its own, so person was loading the class and then the class was loading all the persons so it spammed all the persons over and over again.

Comment: You're using the same navigation property for all joins, you need to define 4 different navigation properties

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = _dbcontext.Person
    .Where(p => p.BuildingId == buildingId)
    .Include(p => p.Building)
    .Include(p => p.Doctor)
    .Include(p => p.Teacher)
    .Include(p => p.Farmer)
    .Include(p => p.Prostitute)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Building;
```